# Html prevent line break between p and div

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

I've got the following problem:

I am trying to put a div with content and more text inside after a `<p></p>` tag.
My problem is, that I don't want a line break after the paragraph tag.

This is my code:

```
<p>Some text</p>

<!-- Dropbox Daten -->
<div class="dropbox">
    <span class="project db_box" data-target="db_index_daten">Daten <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
    <div class="details-dropbox" id="db_index_daten" hidden>
         <div class="box">
            <div class="box-text">
                <p style="text-align: left;">
                   Lorem Ipsum
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Dropbox Daten -->
```

So want it like

```
Some text Data
```

and not like

```
Some text
   Data
```

If you need something else just ask for it.

Comment: What about css you are using for these classes?

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you just need to set `display: inline;` on the elements, that should display in one line.

If you want to keep block properties on the div, use `display: inline-block;`

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
.dropbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can read more about the [`display` attribute on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display). Here is a working example:

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
.dropbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
<div class="dropbox">data</div>
```

Comment: @andreas Dear, do you know what will happen when you increase the text in `<p>`? `inline-block` is wrong. It should be `display: inline`.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, you're right, I was a little bit too fast ;) Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to this...

```css
p, .dropbox{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Stack Over flow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <!-- Dropbox Daten -->
    <div class="dropbox">
        <span class="project db_box" data-target="db_index_daten">Daten <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
        <div class="details-dropbox" id="db_index_daten" hidden>
             <div class="box">
                <div class="box-text">
                    <p style="text-align: left;">
                       Lorem Ipsum
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Dropbox Daten -->
</body>
</html>
```